# spring cloud stream without a source binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm looking to use the spring cloud stream project for my use case. For other reasons I cannot use the kafka binder that comes with spring but would rather use my own custom kafka consumer library to consume messages and then use the message channel mechanisms to drive the messages within the application. On first try the applications fails to start erroring out saying binder missing. So wondering if one cannot use spring cloud stream  with no input binder ? Is it mandatory ? So I added the kafka binder without providing any endpoints. Looks like the application once started keeps checking for kafka running in localhost. In my case, I want to use the kafka library of my own to initiate consumption and then parallel process those messages using the message channel features available in spring cloud stream. Not sure if I'm looking at it the wrong way for my use case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you need to create your own binder, which would be a subclass of `AbstractMessageChannelBinder` and implement all the necessary features. That seems like a lot of work; perhaps it would be better if you edit your question to explain why you can't use the standard Kafka binder.

Comment: Due to library support restrictions we have to use the kafka consumer libraries provided by the enterprise streaming platform. Also I'm trying to implement a use case where I could split our existing streaming application into different modules that are connected by message channels. We want to move away from our existing spark application to something simpler, easy to manage. We call a bunch of api in the streaming application. As a result we lose a lot of monitoring capabilities that are readily available in spark. So looking to seperate out functionalities and have metrics tied to channels.